# How to install MVC3 to pc on multiple visual studio (2010 and 2012) installed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

On the dev pc installed Visual Studio 2010 and MVC3 with Web Platform Installer. Then on this machinery was installed VS2012 Express and I would like for this to be installed MVC3. When I start WPI, can not choose the VS2012:[image: wpi]

I tried [with nuget to install](http://nuget.org/packages/AspNetMvc/3.0.20105.0), but it is only the assembly to install them.

I'd appreciate any assistance, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of at install mvc3, use the Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web.